# How can I connect Microsoft SQL Server to MySQL

Tags: sql-server, mysql

I have a SQL Server running on a local server that is connected to a POS (Point of Sale) system.

I want to create an online application to enable online sales of the products in the POS system.  I'm using MySQL for this application's database.  I would like to connect the MySQL instance to the SQL Server instance to avoid the need to enter duplicate data into each system.  Ideally, changes made to the SQL Server database should be automatically reflected in the MySQL database.

Is there a way to do that with a Linked Server in SQL Server?  Or should I use some other method?  There are around 10,000 products in the SQL Server instance, and we sell around 5,000 each day.

Comment: Please check this link --> https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-create-and-configure-a-linked-server-to-connect-to-mysql-in-sql-server-management-studio/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Linked server and `OPENQUERY` is the right approach.

However, **5k of sales per day** is already a good website. If you are already on MSSQL why don't you use MSSQL for your website? Because you are using `WordPress`? There are solutions for that:

- [Project Nami](https://github.com/ProjectNami/projectnami): It has a few years now so it's quite stable and keeps baing developed. You can also deploy it to Azure quite simply. It might be a good alternative if you are already on MSSQL and if you want to stay there.
- [Ziper](https://zapier.com/apps/sql-server/integrations/wordpress): I've used it in the past, try to give it a go.
- [Skyvia](https://skyvia.com/pricing/): It says it's free up to 5k per month so it really looks like your scenario. You can use it for free now and pay later if you have more than 5k of records per day.

Or if MSSQL and MySQL is what you want and you are good in usingg Microsoft technologies you can use [SSIS](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/mysql-ssis-task-import-2008.rst) to update data from MySQL to MSSQL and vice versa.